# SQL No Dup (Distinct) on rows, but ignore one col

Tags: sql, distinct

For Example, Table with three cols and data

```
col1  col2  col3
 10    20    30
 40    50    60
 40    50    80
```

Want to do a select where for the last two rows only returns one since col1 and col2 are the same.

select distinct will not work since col3 are different.

so output would be

```
 10 20 30
 40 50 xx (don't care)
```

Comment: Which one should be returned? Which RDBMS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you only have one additional column you can just use an arbitrary `MIN`/`MAX` aggregate and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       MAX(col3) AS col3
FROM   YourTable
GROUP  BY col1,
          col2
```

More generally if your RDBMS supports analytic functions you can use

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT col1,
                col2,
                col3,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 
                                       ORDER BY col1, col2) AS RN
         FROM   YourTable)
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       col3
FROM   T
WHERE  RN = 1
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to work fine, also, fyi can say,,,,, (at least in SQLite)

Comment: select *,MAX(col3) as col3 from table group by col1,col2

Comment: The *,MAX(col3) may or may not do it for you, you might get an extra col and unions, etc may not like it.

Answer (score 1):

I did this in SQL Server:

```
-- Setup test data:
declare @table table (
    col1 int,
    col2 int,
    col3 int
)
insert into @table values (10, 20, 30)
insert into @table values (40, 50, 60)
insert into @table values (40, 50, 80)

-- Here's the query:
select col1, col2, cast(min(col3) as varchar(10)) as col3
from @table
group by col1, col2
having count(*) = 1
union all
select col1, col2, 'xx' as col3
from @table
group by col1, col2
having count(*) > 1
```

I suppose this assumes that you have no duplicate rows (where all fields are duplicates), otherwise you'd have a possibly incorrect 'xx'.